# How to describe types using fluent API with EF5

Tags: data-binding, entity-framework-5

I trying to map my classes to existing database, but failed in part of foreign keys declaration. Actually, I do not want to have field-foreign key, but only navigation proerty.
Here is models:

```
public class Template : BaseNamedType
{
    //One template may has multiple TemplateSection
    public virtual ICollection<TemplateSection> TemplateSection { get; set; }
    ...........
}

//Custom mapping class. I have field Order, without it mapping is simple
public class TemplateSection : BaseType
{
    public virtual int Order { get; set; }
    //Here is one-to-many relation, this field is required
    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
    //Here is one-to-many relation, this field is required
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
}

public class Section : BaseNamedType
{
    //One section may be referenced by multiple TemplateSection
    public virtual ICollection<TemplateSection> SectionTemplates { get; set; }
    ...........

}
```

Here is my database creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE [templates]
(
    [id]           INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [name]         NVARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
);

GO;

CREATE TABLE [sections_to_templates]
(
    [section_id]  INT NOT NULL,               //FK to [sections]
    [template_id] INT NOT NULL,               //FK to [templates]
    [order]       INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
);

GO

CREATE TABLE [sections]
(
    [id]           INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [name]         NVARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
);

GO
```

And here in my models binding code, I am absoulte not sure that it is correct:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
    .HasKey(t0 => t0.Id)
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("templates"))
    .Property(x => x.Id)
    .HasColumnName("id")
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
    .IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
    .HasMany(t0 => t0.TemplateSection)
    .WithRequired(t1 => t1.Template)
    .Map(??????????????????)

modelBuilder.Entity<TemplateSection>()
    .HasKey(t0 => t0.Id)
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("sections_to_templates"))
    .Property(x => x.Id)
    .HasColumnName("id")
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
    .IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<TemplateSection>()
    .HasRequired(t0 => t0.Template)
    .WithMany(t1 => t1.TemplateSection)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("template_id"));
modelBuilder.Entity<TemplateSection>()
    .HasRequired(t0 => t0.Section)
    .WithMany(t1 => t1.SectionTemplates)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("section_id"));
//How to describe Section class????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done in my opinion:

- Remove the second mapping block, it is redundant because the relationship is already covered in the fourth mapping block.
- You can remove the `IsRequired()` mappings because non-nullable properties can only be required.
- You can remove the `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` mappings because integer keys are database generated identities by default.
- For the string properties `Name` you can add:

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
      .Property(x => x.Name)
      .HasColumnName("name")
      .HasMaxLength(300)
      .IsRequired();
  // the same for Section
  ```
- "*How to describe Section class????*": Exactly the same way as your first mapping block.

Comment: About 1st point - am I right, if I have symmetrical nvagation properties in 2 classes related as many-to-many, I can setup relation only in 1 block?

Comment: @AlexG.P.: Yes, that's true for every kind of relationship, you only need to configure it from one entity side, not both.

Comment: One more question about your suggestion of adding description of "Name" field: I suspecting that I need to add it if database column name not equal to property name (case insensitive), so actually there is no matter add it or not, right?

Comment: @AlexG.P.: I am actually not sure if you need the mapping if property name and column name only differ by case (it cannot hurt at least). You can test it if it works without the mapping.